# Set x-xsrf-token and send it in header during request RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rtk-query

I have Laravel API + NextJs application with Sanctum authentication.

With Sanctum before sending request to the route, you need to send a request to /sanctum/csrf-cookie 'to initialize csrf protection'.

Here i how my RTK Query API looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcq4T.png)

Here is how the functions are called:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWFwJ.png)

The logic works fine but i wanted to use only RTK Query and not depend on axios. Also, is there any way to handle getting the csrf-cookie and send it during the request from `createAPI()`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671949/617207